# Google charts log scale

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to do a log scale plot in Google Charts(actually a semilogy plot, to be accurate) and have tried
  `vAxis: {
        scaleType: 'log'
  }`
without success. I have seen also Google's example(https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/), but haven't figured out where I am mistaken.
In order to reproduce my problem I've taken the simple Line Chart where i modified some entry values to look similar like values from `f(x) = 1/x`, like my actual data is distributed.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["linechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Index', 'Value'],
                ['1',  100000],
                ['2',  2170],
                ['3',  960],
                ['4',  560],
                ['5',  520],
                ['6',  500],
                ['7',  480],
                ['8',  460],
                ['9',  440],
                ['10',  430],
                ['11',  420],
                ['12',  410],
                ['13',  400],
                ['14',  395],
                ['15',  390],
                ['16',  388],
                ['17',  396],
                ['18',  387],
                ['19',  385],
                ['20',  384]
            ]);

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, legend: 'bottom', title: 'Company Performance', vAxis: {scaleType: 'log'}});
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My last option parameter `vAxis: {scaleType: 'log'}` is ignored. I ahve tried with both discrete and continuous data(1st column both as strings like above or numbers without the '') My plot looks like the one below

[image: log chart test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the updated library (`loader.js`) seems to make a difference

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

instead of...

`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

plus, from the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Index', 'Value'],
      ['1',  100000],
      ['2',  2170],
      ['3',  960],
      ['4',  560],
      ['5',  520],
      ['6',  500],
      ['7',  480],
      ['8',  460],
      ['9',  440],
      ['10',  430],
      ['11',  420],
      ['12',  410],
      ['13',  400],
      ['14',  395],
      ['15',  390],
      ['16',  388],
      ['17',  396],
      ['18',  387],
      ['19',  385],
      ['20',  384]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, legend: 'bottom', title: 'Company Performance', vAxis: {scaleType: 'log'}});
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

here is the same chart, without the option --> `vAxis: {scaleType: 'log'}`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Index', 'Value'],
      ['1',  100000],
      ['2',  2170],
      ['3',  960],
      ['4',  560],
      ['5',  520],
      ['6',  500],
      ['7',  480],
      ['8',  460],
      ['9',  440],
      ['10',  430],
      ['11',  420],
      ['12',  410],
      ['13',  400],
      ['14',  395],
      ['15',  390],
      ['16',  388],
      ['17',  396],
      ['18',  387],
      ['19',  385],
      ['20',  384]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, legend: 'bottom', title: 'Company Performance'});
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Google documentation is sometimes confusing with all the frequent changes.

Comment: @WhiteHat, Can you tell me how can we use log scale for time series in bubble charts? I can't find it anywhere where we can have log scale for time series example, I tried the below link but couldn't made it work for time series on x-axis with log scale.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#axis-scale