# How to change format to number from string, except first row in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

Hi I have google chart with following data,

```
$scope.datax =[
       ["Release Date","R1","R2","R3"],
          ["Mon Apr 11 00:00:00 IST 2016","20","13","70"],
          ["Wed May 11 00:00:00 IST 2016","20","13","60"],
          ["Sat Jun 11 00:00:00 IST 2016","20","13","50"]
       ]
```

I need this format to like following i,e numbers should not contain quotes " ",

```
$scope.datax =[
           ["Release Date","R1","R2","R3"],
              ["Mon Apr 11 00:00:00 IST 2016", 20, 13, 70],
              ["Wed May 11 00:00:00 IST 2016", 20, 13, 60],
              ["Sat Jun 11 00:00:00 IST 2016", 20, 13, 50]
           ]
```

It will be really good if this can be done using any of format spcecifiers function of google chart only rather than iterating it again. Here is my working fiddle with dummy data without double quets "", [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/98yayp52/)
and this is demo with strings as numbers [Demo with original data](http://jsfiddle.net/83nsngov/)

I cant change data because its coming from server call and I am adding rows based on clicks made by user. Please anyone share you idea or fiddle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17nkej5t/) using a DataView to convert the numbers without using jquery...

Comment: @WhiteHat can you please tell me, why we need to include google/jsapi? to work with charts is there anything that I can make my graph non-dependant on that load?

Comment: actually, you should be using `loader.js` instead of `jsapi`, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes) --> _The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on..._ -- but you must have one of them, it is the source code for drawing the charts. -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352116/google-charts-log-scale/40367253#40367253) for example using `loader.js`...

Comment: @WhiteHat my graph first time coming very small I need it to take 100% width, can you please suggest anything?

Comment: make sure the chart's container is visible before drawing the first time -- by default the chart will follow the size of the container...

Comment: Thank you sir you are awesome

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat can you please take a look at this question sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587293/how-to-customize-angular-google-chart-legend-info

Comment: @WhiteHat  while uglyfying code in script.js its throwig error for map function for > the error is like this >> Uglifying source dist/scripts/scripts.js failed. Warning: Uglification failed. Unexpected token: operator (>). Line 7053 in dist/scripts/scripts.js

I have used map. the one which I accepted below. Any alternate solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New solution, not that agressive in converting:

```
 $scope.datax=$scope.datax.map(row=>row.map(e=>+e||e));
```

Old solution, wich also converted dates...

```
$scope.datax=$scope.datax.map(row=>row.map(e=>parseInt(e,10)||e));
```

---

the problem noted in the comment is from the fn shorthand `=>`

try replacing with regular function...

```
$scope.datax=$scope.datax.map(function (row) {
  return row.map(function (e) {
    return +e||e;
  });
});
```

Comment: please add the radix to `parseInt`, otherwise a zero starting number get read as octal number.

Comment: It seems like there's no option from the API to parse ints inside of the chart. Upvoting your answer.

Comment: @Jonasw I just noticed big problem here, even first row getting parsed so my dates are now also become integers, please provide any other solution.

Comment: Hi @Jonasw I have one more requirement, if you can help me, I have to implement autocomplete on typehead, like how user types need to show matching results in oi-select editable dropdown. Any solution link you have please give, thanks in advance. I can create new question for this if you want.

Comment: @Jonasw while uglyfying code in script.js its throwig error for map function for > the error is like this >> Uglifying source dist/scripts/scripts.js failed.
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: operator (>).
Line 7053 in dist/scripts/scripts.js

Comment: Any alternate solution ? instead of using >

Comment: @Jonasw I got it, your method is good but I am facing problem while doing grunt build in my application its throwing error for using =>, anyhow I am giving you plus one mark(upvote) thank alot. but whitehat answer is what i needed.

Comment: @Jonasw sir I agree, your ans is right only, but I added both of u a comment saying I dont need in => way, so he replied I have to accept that answer, Sorry but please understand it was urgently needed.

Comment: @Jonasw can you try this question sir? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829631/how-to-convert-javascript-google-chart-to-angularjs-google-chart

Comment: Sorry Jonasw I didnt know that your ans and whitehat ans are same by little difference, here I have accepted your ans, thanks a lot for help.