# How to customize angular google chart legend info

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have google chart (line chart), need to customize legend with some extra information. Please refer this   `http://plnkr.co/edit/ysZwYaAQpMhHarcA2UHq?p=preview` `[Plunker][1]` to know more in detail. I want legend information like this below snap [image: Required change in legend snap]

So if you see in below image, and my fiddle I have R1, R2 , R3 and so on as releases to select, and each release has its own score, so I want that score to be shown as R1 100 just like below image. 
Note that graph data is different, and the dropdown for selection of releases data is different. but both have releaseId R1 , R2. So on selection of dropdown value say R1,R2 or R3 I am pushing only that row from graphdata to drawgraph.

So basically, I need to show selected R1 score in legend.

Please give me some idea or link where this is done earlier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: little hard to follow, you just want the score in the legend? the legend displays the column heading in the data table, add the score to the column heading...

Comment: Please check plunker once you might understand. Actually graph data is different, and dropdown option data is different. On r1 selecting I am pushing r1 to graph draw. Now I only need that extrem right side legend in graph which is score R1 100, R2 150 R3 186.

Comment: @WhiteHat how to increase width for legends? I mean its showing ... after some content. Is there any way?

Comment: there's something going wrong, if I pick R2, then pick R4, it still only shows R2. it's like they have to be in order. if i pick R2, then R3 it works. if i pick R3, then R5, it doesn't. -- to give more room on right for legend, reduce `chartArea.width` or set less than `width`, e.g. -- `chartArea: {width: 600}`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/dYXyIub4HackZ7JjHxan?p=preview check this sir, actually graph data was only for r1,r2,r3 only so it was not coming , now check above plnkr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add the score to the legend,
you can add the score to the column label before drawing the chart

replace the `drawChart` function with the following...

```
    function drawChart() {
        var chartColors = [];
        var chartColumns = [0];
        var checks = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedNewRelease.length; i++) {
            var seriesColumn = getColumnIndex(x, $scope.selectedNewRelease[i].releaseId);
            chartColumns.push(seriesColumn);
            x.setColumnLabel(seriesColumn, x.getColumnLabel(seriesColumn) + ' ' + $scope.selectedNewRelease[i].score);
        }
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(x);
        view.setColumns(chartColumns);
        chart.draw(view, options);
          if ($scope.selectedNewRelease.length>0) {
                $scope.Grtgraph=true;
            }else{
                $scope.Grtgraph=false;
            }
    }

    function getColumnIndex(data, columnLabel) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        if (data.getColumnLabel(i) === columnLabel) {
          return i;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks aton and one upvote, cant we do seperately like in my snap? i mean in rounded colored dots we can show score in front of that rounded dot?

Comment: sir one major problem I have with all my work done till today, whatever requirements did are using google jsapi which dont have bower support, so I cant host it as my project uses bower to load libraries, I have created new question in which I explained my problem, I need my code in angularjs google chart way please have a look on this question sir, probably last help for google chart please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829631/how-to-convert-javascript-google-chart-to-angularjs-google-chart

Comment: I have added new question for my comment, you know my code now, can you please help me in writing same code using angularjs Google chart method instead of jsapi ?

Comment: Oh can we install Google jsapi using bower ?

Comment: Sir please check example of line chart I have given in my question.

Comment: sir can please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190277/how-to-handle-error-in-google-charts-when-entire-column-has-null-values